# Use mobile phone number as account ID so users dont have to register?

Tags: users, theming

Im making a mobile first site. Is there a way of using a user's mobile phone number so they dont have to register for an account?

Or, if a user creates an account the normal way on a desktop and enters their phone number, is it possible to detect when the visit the site with a phone from that number and log them in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the visitor's phone number when they visit your website from their phone. O2 recently [got into a bit of trouble](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/01/25/o2_hands_out_phone_numbers_to_websites/) for sending the user's mobile number in the request headers.

According to the article:

> Rival 3G networks are not appending visitors' phone numbers to the HTTP headers.

So I'm afraid there's no way to do this automatically.

You might want to look into building an app for the various platforms if that's an option, I believe in that context you do have access to the user's phone number.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want detect that a user is recuring user? Generaly this can be done with a cookie.

Tecnicaly there is no reason to use a phone number. As far as I know there's no possibility for a web application to get the phonenumber automatically. A solution could be an app as frontend which delegates to the website.